# If I have a property do I need a field as well?

Tags: c#, properties, field

So after the availability of automatic implementation, and initialization of a property, do I even need a field for my property?

This seems much cleaner:

```
class A {
public int X {
        get;set;
    } = 1;
}
```

Than this:

```
class A {
    int x = 1;
    public int X {
        get {
            return x;
        }
        set {
            x = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, the compiler is already providing a backing field - it's just implicit (and it's given a name that you can't refer to in code). Note that there *has* to be a backing field in the generated code, as a property itself is really just a pair of methods with some metadata linking them - the presence of a property does not add any state to the object. State is *only* stored in fields.

It's even cleaner when written on one line - I'd usually see this as:

```
class A
{
    public int X { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a backing field in this situation, but if you want to manipulate the Property with e.g a OnPropertyChanged() then you need to have a backing field

```
public int X {
    get {
        return x;
    }
    set {           
        x = value;
        OnPropertyChanged()
    }
}
```